# Imprimir numero de procesos ejecutados en c

Tags: c, proceso

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde quiero imprimir el numero de procesos ejcutados.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  int n = 70;
  int pid[n]; /* Suponga contenido iniciado en 0 */
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    pid[i] = fork();
    int childpid = getpid();
    if (childpid == 0) {
      if ((pid[0] > 0) && (pid[n - 1] == 0)) {
        if (fork())
          fork();
      }
      exit(0);
    }
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Intente hacer un print del sizeof(pid[n]) pero esto no dió el resultado que esperaba. ¿Como puedo saber el numero de procesos creados en la ejecución del programa entonces?

Comment: Recuerda que `sizeof` se resuelve en tiempo de compilación, excepto cuando lo usas con un arreglo de longitud variable. Así todo, obtendrías el tamaño del arreglo, no la cantidad de elementos actualmente en uso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que el proceso hijo todavía está en ejecución y si el último proceso hijo ya ha terminado de ejecutarse antes de crear dos nuevos procesos hijos.

*Para contar la cantidad de procesos, solo iterar hasta la cantidad proporcionada*, `int n = 70`, *y verificar si el proceso actual es mayor que* **0**  *incrementará con una variable auxiliar.*

```
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int pid = getpid();
    if (pid > 0) {
      conteo++;
    }
  }
```

En esta condición

```
if (pid > 0)
```

Lo que se está verificando es si el proceso actual es un proceso padre.

código completo

```
int main(void) {
  int n = 70;
  int pid[n]; /* Suponga contenido iniciado en 0 */
  int i;
  int conteo = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    pid[i] = fork();
    int childpid = getpid();
    if (childpid == 0) {
      exit(0);
    }
  }

 
  if ((pid[0] > 0) && (pid[n - 1] > 0 || pid[n - 1] == 0)) {
    if (fork())
      fork();
  }

  //número de processos criados
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int pid = getpid();
    if (pid > 0) {
      conteo++;
    }
  }

  printf("procesos = %d", conteo);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: la condicion if(pid > 0) es para verificar si un proceso es padre o hijo? porque si es mayor a 0 significa que es un hijo ya que el padre se inicializa en 0 no?

Comment: si el proceso actual es un proceso padre

Comment: entonces por ejemplo este condicional if (pid[0] > 0) && (pid[n - 1] == 0) verifica si el primer proceso del arreglo es padre y el ultimo es hijo? Perdón por preguntar tanto pero estoy intentado entender este tema de procesos

Comment: Sí, es así como lo estás comprobando. Tienes razón.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!